# Inequality based conditional cumulative sum

Tags: r

I have been trying to do code this:
For each $\left(  x,z\right)  \in\left(  X,Z\right):$

$r(x,z)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i}1\{X_{i}<=x\}1\left\{  Z_{i}<=z\right\}$

So far, the best way I came up to do this is by using a loop. Here an example:

```
y=rnorm(10)
x=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4)
z=c(5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9)
data=data.frame(y,x,z)    
s=rep(NA,length(unique(x))*length(unique(z)))
dim(s)=c(length(unique(x)),length(unique(z)))
for (i in 1:length(unique(x))){
for (j in 1:length(unique(z))){
   s[i,j]=sum(y*as.numeric((x<=unique(x)[i]))*
                as.numeric((z<=unique(z)[j])))
}
}
```

The output is OK, but given that once the dimension of x and z grows, this becomes quite slow.Since, for a given z, this looks like a conditional cumulative sum,  I am 100% sure that there is a more efficient way of doing this, without the loop.

Would any of you have any suggestion? If I didn't have z, I know I could use data.table:

```
 s=data[order(x)][,lapply(.SD, sum),by=c("x"), .SDcols=c("y")]
  s=s[,lapply(.SD, cumsum), .SDcols=c("y")]
```

but with more than one index (x and z, not just x) I was not able to formulate the program.

Comment: You don't need `as.numeric`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
y=rnorm(10)
x=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4)
z=c(5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9)

x.mat=matrix(x,nrow=length(unique(x)),ncol=length(x),byrow=TRUE)
x.mat.u=matrix(unique(x),nrow=length(unique(x)),ncol=length(x))
xx=x.mat<=x.mat.u

z.mat=matrix(z,nrow=length(unique(z)),ncol=length(z),byrow=TRUE)
z.mat.u=matrix(unique(z),nrow=length(unique(z)),ncol=length(z))
zz=z.mat<=z.mat.u

yy=matrix(y,nrow=length(unique(z)),ncol=length(z),byrow=TRUE)


xx%*%t(zz*yy)
```

Comment: Well, this would work for the particular case I give, I must say. However, if I have 5 dimensions, how should I proceed?! That's my main problem

Comment: I just managed to get the generalization, using nested Lapply functions. But the idea was exactly as @Stat mentioned. Thanks